# Fragment error, transaction.replace()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to resolve this error and I believe that I'm mixing support libraries, however, I'm not sure on how to adjust my code so that I stop getting an error.

```
  import android.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.view.View;

public void swapFragment(View v) {
    SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.findBox)).commit();
    transaction = transaction.replace(R.id.findBox, searchFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

The error occurs in the following line:

```
    transaction = transaction.replace(R.id.findBox, searchFragment);
```

The second parameter causes an error saying its the wrong argument.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong without looking at all the source, but you have a `remove` *and* a `replace` right away. You don't need both. Just do a replace (that does a remove -> add behind the scenes).

Also add the `import` statements, to see what type SearchFragment is (and what Fragment Manager / Fragment Transaction you're using).

If you're using the v4 support library, you must make sure they are all the Support versions.

*UPDATE*

Looking at your imports…

You have `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;` but you're using `import android.app.FragmentManager;`.

So your code should look like:

```
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.findbox, new SearchFragment());
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

And your imports should be more like:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

*Assuming `SearchFragment extends Fragment`* using that support library version.

Comment: Admittedly I'm using auto-imports and they are largely guiding my hand as I'm very much a beginner. Perhaps this is not best practice, even for a newbie. And yes, SearchFragment extends Fragment.

Comment: I disabled auto-imports a long time ago, Android is tricky with some imports and Android Studio doesn't always pick the best choice. The "hurdle" of having to go one by one and picking from a list is worth to avoid these problems :)

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the fragment, and then trying to replace the removed fragment. Try something like this instead:

```
FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
SearchFragment F1 = new SearchFragment();
FT.replace(R.id.findBox, searchFragment);
FT.commit();
```

Comment: I will be testing this out shortly. Let you know how it goes!

Comment: In your case you can use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting the same error.....
I wish this solution helps you in your problem.
In the `SearchFragment.java` file of which you have created the instance as `SearchFragment` in your code. Go to that file and `import android.app.Fragment` and remove `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` if mentioned. Hopefully your error will rectified as this has worked in my case.